# Excel - compare 2 lists

Tags: excel, compare

I have 2 lists, 2 columns. 
First column is registered users with a certain ID, name, Nick, etc'.

At second column, random people write in their ID. 
I want only for registered ones to be auto filled with other info (name, Nick....). If not registered - error.

I do not have a lot of knowledge on this, but it's my last project.

Many thanks !!

Comment: I am not clear on whether people are entering values in both columns or just the ID column.

Comment: Hey Adam, people are entering on both. Registered on first, and on second everybody writes ID. I want to compare the IDs, and for registered ones - to complete the rest of info